# Finding the limit of $\dfrac{\sin x}{2x}$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\sin 0= 0$ and $2\cdot 0=0$, how can the answer be $1/2$?

Am I missing a step?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: The most important reason for introducing the concept of limits in the first place is to deal with limits of expressions in which the numerator and denominator both approach $0$. That is what happens in the expression $\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)−f(x)}h$. So it would be a serious mistake to think that if the numerator and denominator both have $0$ as their limits, then the limit of the fraction does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you need to evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{2x}$$ We have
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{2x}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \right) \tag{*}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

To evaluate the limit inside the parenthesis in (*) we are using the well known
theorem from Calculus, that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. For a nice geometric proof of this fact you can see [Robjohn's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1). If the OP is taking a calculus I class in the US it is very likely that your textbook uses a similar technique to prove this theorem. This is one of the so called fundamental limits that one has to know in Calculus I.

Of course once that theorem is proved it can be used freely in evaluating such limits. The point of these kinds of problems is precisely to get you to use that theorem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x }{2x}=\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}}_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

> $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \overset{ l'Hospital}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \cos x=1$

Comment: Do you remember L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Yes,I know that we could prove it with L'Hopital's rule..

Comment: Using L'hopital's rule to evaluate this limit would be circular reasoning. Because if one uses L'hopital's rule then we need the derivative of $\sin x$, but to find it you need to evaluate a limit of the form $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: To complement @JackDawkins's comment, it's circular if you're using the geometric definition of $\sin$ and it's likely that this is the definition being used.

Comment: @evinda whoops, the comment was meant for the OP. Put the comment in the wrong section. Apologies.

Comment: @user137481 Never mind...

Comment: DeL'Hospital? It should be either l'Hôpital (modern French), or l'Hospital (old French). And spelled like *L'Hopital's rule*, it has 2 spelling mistakes.

Comment: @IlikeSerena I edited my post :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember, we're not evaluating $\frac{\sin(x)}{2x}$ when $x=0$.  If we were to do so, the answer would be undefined (since division by 0 is undefined).  Instead, we are asking what is the limit of the value $\frac{\sin(x)}{2x}$ as $x$ gets closer and closer to 0.  And that's a very different question.

This value can be determined using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: We have not been taught that in my class. Is there a simpler explanation?

Comment: @user137452 "simple" is a relative term. Try this website:http://www.larsoncalculus.com/calc10/content/proof-videos/chapter-1/section-3/proof-two-special-trigonometric-limits/#content-top

Comment: I guess you could use the definition of a limit, but I'm not sure it would be simple to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The **most important reason** for introducing the concept of limits in the first place is to deal with limits of expressions in which the numerator and denominator both approach $0$.

That is what happens in the expression $\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h$.

So it would be a serious mistake to think that if the numerator and denominator both have $0$ as their limits, then the limit of the fraction does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x\sim x$ around $0$, then $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}.$$